# Not opening file

Tags: java, android, pdf

I am making an app called ROME, about the city of Rome. I have a activity called eten which means food and I want the activity to open a certain pdf-file called etenlijst.pdf when openened.

I got to the following code:

```
public class Eten extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_eten);
// Show the Up button in the action bar.
// getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



    /****  This looks like a good place for it   *****/

   Button OpenPDF = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OpenPdfButton);
    OpenPDF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    { 
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        File pdfFile = new File("/ROME/Etenlijst.pdf"); 
        if(pdfFile.exists()) 
        {
            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile); 
            Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
            pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            try
            {
                startActivity(pdfIntent);
            }
            catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(Eten.this, "Installeer een geschikte applicatie om PDF's mee te openen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            }
        }

    }
});
}
}
```

But whenever I go to this activity in my app or click the button it won't open the file or give the toast?
Do you now why?

Thanks in advance,
Ide

Comment: Does you program throws any exception? If yes then please add that exception. Are you giving the correct path for your file? and what this `pdfFile.exists()` statement returns?

Comment: It doesn't open the file, because it's 99% certain that there is no file in the `/ROME` path of internal memory. Are you including it as an asset?

Comment: There is no exception and I have the pdf Etenlijst.pdf just copied into the project folder in Eclipse.

Comment: @Ide try `System.out.println("File Status" +pdfFile.exists())` just before `if` block and see what it returns? if its true then problem could be somewhere else and need to debug code.

Comment: With the File constructor you're assuming that the file is in your SD card. If you want to open the pdf file that it's in your Eclipse project, you nedd to use Assets

Comment: How can you use assets?

Comment: Thanks for all the help and effort Guys! I found another way to solve my problem than using an pdf-file, but despite lots of thanks!